# panstart and panmove is not working on Android devices in Firefox browser

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I am working on the Angular7 project and I am using hammerjs version 2.0.1. I have a map which I need to pan on mobile devices. I checked on android devices. it works fine on chrome browser but on firefox, it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="view-image"  (panmove)="onPanMove($event)" (panstart)="onPanStart($event)" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i Faced the same issue , problem was high level element's event was overriding child event.
for example,

```
 <div (mouseover)="selectPage()">
    <div (panstart)="handlePanStart($event)">...</div>
 </div>
```

because of this my panstart and panmove was not working. so see if You have something like that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)